# Calling a tkinter window variable so that it can be used in another function

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

For this code, my intent is to add a function to add data that the user enters into a database. I already have a function set up to create the user interface in order to let them enter data and another function to retrieve the data. However, i get an error message saying that the DeliveryInterface variable hasn't been defined. Is there a way to get the add data function to recognize the DeliveryInterface variable from the last function? I attach the segment of code that is causing the issue.

```
        def InputScreen():
             DeliveryInterface = tkinter.Tk() #creates the interface for the input screen
             DeliveryInterface.title('Input New Data') #gives the new window a title
             DeliveryInterface.geometry('400x500') #sets the default size of the window as 400 x 500
             DeliveryInterface.maxsize(400, 500) #sets the maximum size of the interface as 400 x 500
             DeliveryInterface.configure(background='#0092FF') #sets the background colour of the inteface to the light blue as seen in the main menu interface
            (.......)
            StockIDLabel = tkinter.Label(DeliveryInterface, text='Stock ID', font=('Helvetica', 16))  # creates a label that tells the user that the next box is associated with the stock id
            StockIDLabel.place(x=30, y=60, height=22, width=200)

            StockID_entry = tkinter.Entry(DeliveryInterface, font=('Helvetica', 16))  # creates the entry box for the stock ID
            StockID_entry.place(x=250, y=60, height=22, width=100)
            (...........)
         def addingNewStock():
             StockID = 0 #Initialises the stock ID
             StockID = DeliveryInterface.StockID_entry.get() #intended to get the data from the entrybox, however, i get an error message say that DeliveryInterface hasnt been defined
            print (StockID) #prints the stockID so that i now if the variable has been changed.
```

I hope this is all the information needed, Thank you

Comment: Variables defined in one function are local to the defining function. Also, your indentation is messed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make `DeliveryInterface` global:

```
    def InputScreen():
         global DeliveryInterface
         DeliveryInterface = tkinter.Tk() #creates the interface for the input screen
         DeliveryInterface.title('Input New Data') #gives the new window a title
         DeliveryInterface.geometry('400x500') #sets the default size of the window as 400 x 500
         DeliveryInterface.maxsize(400, 500) #sets the maximum size of the interface as 400 x 500
         DeliveryInterface.configure(background='#0092FF') #sets the background colour of the inteface to the light blue as seen in the main menu interface
        (.......)
        StockIDLabel = tkinter.Label(DeliveryInterface, text='Stock ID', font=('Helvetica', 16))  # creates a label that tells the user that the next box is associated with the stock id
        StockIDLabel.place(x=30, y=60, height=22, width=200)

        StockID_entry = tkinter.Entry(DeliveryInterface, font=('Helvetica', 16))  # creates the entry box for the stock ID
        StockID_entry.place(x=250, y=60, height=22, width=100)
        (...........)
     def addingNewStock():
         StockID = 0 #Initialises the stock ID
         StockID = DeliveryInterface.StockID_entry.get() #intended to get the data from the entrybox, however, i get an error message say that DeliveryInterface hasnt been defined
        print (StockID) #prints the stockID so that i now if the variable has been changed.
```

Another option is to use python 3's `nonlocal` keyword.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you're facing is that variables have their scope - you have defined DeliveryInterface to exist in InputScreen() - and it's not going to exist anywhere else.

You have a few options how to solve this:

Make it a global variable. This is usually frowned upon and being considered a bad practice but still can be reasonable.

Make the InputScreen a class which would have a method for initialization and adding a new stock. By doing so, the class will remember its state - the values of the variables.

Or pass the DeliveryInterface as an argument to the addingNewStock() function. If you're calling this function right from the function InputScreen() then this would be the easiest solution.